# Node.js net: socket.write - Part of the string doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, irc

I'm using the net module. I do socket.write but only part of the string appears.

```
    var id = data.slice(2,3).toString('binary').charCodeAt(0);
    var msg = data.slice(3).toString('binary');
    gotMessage(id, msg);
```

This is where I obtain the message, it's msg.

```
var packet = ":" + nick + "!~" + nick + "@" + server.serverName + " PRIVMSG " + cname + " :" + msg);
socket.write(packet + "\x0D\x0A", 'binary');
console.log("Sent: " + packet);
```

console.log outputs the message without any problems, socket.write only outputs part of it, msg doesn't appear. It appears in the IRC client as: "Name:", but no message.

Comment: That first line in the second code snippet is syntactically incorrect. Is that a transcription error?

Comment: I fixed it, it was an error with copying.

Comment: What exactly does `console.log()` show? Does the `msg` string have any control characters in it that might cause a problem?

Comment: No, normal alphabet characters. console.log shows exactly what socket.write should also show. But socket.write only outputs the string without the msg in the IRC client.